# How to make iOS show location allert consistently?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

> turn on location services to allow to determine your location

When we try to access location services this pop up. However it doesn't pop up consistently. I think it shows up once. How do I make iOS show it consistently?

Note: I am aware that there is a question here: [get alert for current location every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075337/get-alert-for-current-location-every-time). All the answers talk about how you should change the settings. That's what the user should do. I want **iOS** to pop up alert consistently to users.

Comment: That's a different question. This is from programmer point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert shows up automatically when we call

```
[singleton.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

A common mistake noobs like me make is to check first whether location update is enabled or not and then not calling that line when it's not. So the alert doesn't show up.

Coincidentally those are the exact pattern recommended by IOS. Many questions almost the same thing but none of the answers there point to this fact.

Answer (score 0):

well this option pops up when there location service is disabled.and it is needed only there. so the question for you is

why ? why you want to show it consistently?

Comment: Yes I want it to show up every time location service is disabled.